# Why don't my system calls work in the Perl program I wrap with pp?

Tags: perl, activeperl, par, perl-packager

I have a Perl/POE/Tk script running on Win32 ActivePerl that calls executables using `system`. I created an exe of the script using `pp`. I can unpack the exe and see the executables off the root of the "zip" file directory, but when I run the exe and try to use the functionality of the system calls I get a "file not found" type of error;

```
'..\cpau' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

cpau.exe is one of the included files.

`pp` is called thus:

```
pp -i alias3.ico -g -a add_event.job -a add_rec.job -a CPAU.exe -a del_event.job -a del_rec.job -a dnscmd.exe -a eventcreate.exe -o alias_v_3-0.exe alias_poe_V-3_0_par.pl
```

I am guessing that I need to adjust the path of the `system` calls. I currently am trying to use the default path;

```
system("cpau -dec -file add_rec.job -nowarn -wait");
```

I tried this:

```
system("..\cpau -dec -file ..\add_rec.job -nowarn -wait");
```

reasoning that pp put the script in the \scripts\ directory, but no joy. Any suggestions?

Comment: CPAU.exe is a separate file as indicated below;

pp -i alias3.ico -g -a CPAU.exe -a add_event.job -a add_rec.job -a del_event.job -a del_rec.job -a dnscmd.exe -a eventcreate.exe -o alias_v_3-0.exe alias_poe_V-3_0_par.pl

fork might get a bit doggie as the whole thing is running within POE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** My *suggestions below do not work*. However, I am going to leave them up in case someone else has a similar question. This answer shows a lot of things that may sound reasonable but do not work.

See the [**discussion following the OP's repost**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125689/where-does-pp-par-unpack-added-a-files) for code [using $ENV{PAR_TEMP}](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/PAR::Environment) that **solves** the OP's problem

**FOR REFERENCE**

[pp docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?pp) say:

> -a, --addfile=FILE|DIR
>   ...
>
> > By default, files are placed under / inside the package with their original names.

By using system, you are asking `cmd.exe` to find the file and I now realize that probably is a losing battle unless you have a separate executable called `cpau.exe`. I do not have time to try this right now, but a you might have to do the `fork` and `exec` yourself instead of relying on `system`. As in:

```
exec 'CPAU.exe', @args
```

**Previous answer:**

The string you pass to `system` does not contain what you think it does:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x= "..\cpau -dec -file ..\add_rec.job -nowarn -wait";

print $x, "\n";
__END__

C:\Temp> fgh
..►au -dec -file ..dd_rec.job -nowarn -wait
```

Use (*edited following OP's comment below*):

```
system "..\\cpau -dec -file ../add_rec.job -nowarn -wait";
```

I would also recommend using the list form of `system`:

```
system '..\\cpau', qw(-dec -file ../add_rec.job -nowarn -wait);
```

In addition, you might find [FindBin](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FindBin) handy if you want to specify the path to `cpau` relative to the current script's directory.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin qw($Bin);
use File::Spec::Functions qw( catfile );

my $program = catfile $Bin, '..', 'cpau';

system $program, qw(-dec -file ../add_rec.job -nowarn -wait);

__END__
```

Comment: Or `"..\\.."` or `'..\..'` if the command is broken and handles / specially (as opposed to just passing them through to the Win32 API, which globally understands both / and \ as path delimiters).

Comment: Tried system '../cpau', qw(-dec -file ../add_rec.job -nowarn -wait);

Got back;
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: system '.\\cpau', qw(-dec -file .\\add_rec.job -nowarn -wait);
works if directory where the exe is has the other files already in it, but not if the exe is in a directory by itself.

Comment: @jpolache Updated my answer in light of your comments above.

Comment: Added recommended code.  Ran pp-created exe from an empty directory. Error message as follows;

'C:\cpau' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that a another call to an executable in the code was working.  I looked and found that the call that was working used backtics rather than a system()call.  I changed the other calls to backtics and the problem went away.

`.\\cpau -dec -file .\\del_rec.job -nowarn -wait`;

So, this fixes the problem, buy why?  What is the difference between system() and a backtic in the win32 shell?

Spoke too soon. This works in a directory where cpau already exists. When I tried it in c:\temp I got the "'cpau' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." error. Very frustrating.

I'm stumped.

`cpau -dec -file del_rec.job -nowarn -wait`;

I tried it with and without the leanding ".\\". Same error either way.